# Why do dict keys support list subtraction but not tuple subtraction?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Presumably dict_keys are supposed to behave as a set-like object, but they are lacking the `difference` method and the subtraction behaviour seems to diverge.

```
>>> d = {0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
>>> d.keys() - [0, 2]
{1, 3}
>>> d.keys() - (0, 2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Why does dict_keys class try to iterate an integer here?  Doesn't that violate duck-typing?

---

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(['0', '1', '01']).keys() - ('01',)
{'01'}
>>> dict.fromkeys(['0', '1', '01']).keys() - ['01',]
{'1', '0'}
```

Comment: Tuples are immutable, and could therefore be keys of the dictionary themselves, in which case this would be ambiguous — if not syntactically then at least in the mind of a programmer.

Comment: @L3viathan I'm not convinced, because `dict.fromkeys('0123').keys() - '02'` still works

Comment: Are only `tuple`s of `int`s special? `dict.fromkeys('0123').keys() - ('0', '2')` gives `{'1', '3'}`.

Comment: Interestingly, dictionary view-mappings are supposed to be 'set'-like, but sets do not support this: `set((0,1,2,3)) - [0,2]` results in *unsupported operand for 'set' and 'str'*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This looks to be a bug. [The implementation is to convert the `dict_keys` to a `set`, then call `.difference_update(arg)` on it.](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Objects/dictobject.c#l3437)

It looks like they misused `_PyObject_CallMethodId` (an optimized variant of `PyObject_CallMethod`), by passing a format string of just `"O"`. [Thing is, `PyObject_CallMethod` and friends are documented to require a `Py_BuildValue` format string that "should produce a `tuple`"](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallMethod). With more than one format code, it wraps the values in a `tuple` automatically, but with only one format code, it doesn't `tuple`, it just creates the value (in this case, because it's already `PyObject*`, all it does is increment the reference count).

While I haven't tracked down where it might be doing this, I suspect somewhere in the internals it's identifying `CallMethod` calls that don't produce a `tuple` and wrapping them to make a one element `tuple` so the called function can actually receive the arguments in the expected format. When subtracting a `tuple`, it's already a `tuple`, and this fix up code never activates; when passing a `list`, it does, becoming a one element `tuple` containing the `list`.

`difference_update` takes varargs (as if it were declared `def difference_update(self, *args)`). So when it receives the unwrapped `tuple`, it thinks it's supposed to subtract away the elements from each entry in the `tuple`, not treat said entries as values to subtract away themselves. To illustrate, when you do:

```
mydict.keys() - (1, 2)
```

the bug is causing it to do (roughly):

```
result = set(mydict)
# We've got a tuple to pass, so all's well...
result.difference_update(*(1, 2)) # Unpack behaves like difference_update(1, 2)
# OH NO!
```

While:

```
mydict.keys() - [1, 2]
```

does:

```
result = set(mydict)
# [1, 2] isn't a tuple, so wrap
result.difference_update(*([1, 2],)) # Behaves like difference_update([1, 2])
# All's well
```

That's why a `tuple` of `str` works (incorrectly), `- ('abc', '123')` is performing a call equivalent to:

```
result.difference_update(*('abc', '123'))
# or without unpacking:
result.difference_update('abc', '123')
```

and since `str`s are iterables of their characters, it just blithely removes entries for `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, etc. instead of `'abc'` and `'123'` like you expected.

Basically, this is a bug; [it's filed against the CPython folks](https://bugs.python.org/issue26478) and fixed in 3.6.0 (as well as later releases of 2.7, 3.4, and 3.5).

The correct behavior probably should have been to call (assuming this `Id` variant exists for this API):

```
_PyObject_CallMethodObjArgsId(result, &PyId_difference_update, other, NULL);
```

which wouldn't have the packing issues at all, and would run faster to boot; the smallest change would be to change the format string to `"(O)"` to force `tuple` creation even for a single item, but since the format string gains nothing, `_PyObject_CallMethodObjArgsId` is better.