# Difference in behavior of intersection between dict.viewkeys() and tuple between 2.7.10 and 2.7.13

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

So, after reading through the changelogs between the 2 versions, Python 2.7.10 and Python 2.7.13, nothing popped out at me that would explain the following behavior.

**Python 2.7.10**

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug  7 2015, 10:34:58) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> d = dict(foo='bar', bar='baz', fee='fum', baz='fee')
>>> keys = ('baz', 'bar')
>>> d.viewkeys() & keys
set([])
```

**Python 2.7.13**

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 17 2016, 23:03:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> d = dict(foo='bar', bar='baz', fee='fum', baz='fee')
>>> keys = ('baz', 'bar')
>>> d.viewkeys() & keys
set(['bar', 'baz'])
```

I was wondering if someone has an explanation for this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this text in [What's New in Python 2.7.13](https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/v2.7.13/Misc/NEWS) outlines the issue:

> - Issue #26478: Fix semantic bugs when using binary operators with dictionary   views and tuples.

See the relevant [bug issue 26478](https://bugs.python.org/issue26478) and [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784258/why-do-dict-keys-support-list-subtraction-but-not-tuple-subtraction) for details